# Really confused about promise being returned from async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

So I do know that async function returns a pending promise as soon as it hits the await keyword and if there's no await keyword used, the promise that async function returns will be resolved to the value that we return from our async function like this:

```js
async function f() {
    let p = await (new Promise(r => {
        setTimeout(r, 2000, 100)
    }))
    return p;
}

let p = f();
console.log(p); // pending, because its awaiting.
```

2nd Example:

```js
async function f() {
    let p = 'someValue';
    return p;
}
let p = f();
console.log(p); // {<fulfilled>: "someValue"}
```

2nd example also makes perfect sense, we're returning 'someValue' which as MDN says is wrapped in Promise.resolve('someValue') and that's what that's returned.

Now, what this code prints confuses me so much, it logs a pending promise!

**(I know I'm not using await here and that's intentional)**

```js
async function f() {
    let p = new Promise(r => r(113));
    return p;
}
let af = f();
console.log(af)
```

We are creating a promise inside our async f function that's resolved immediately and that's the promise I return in my default created promise of async function so why does that log pending?

And even though its pending, when I expand that object, I see this at the same time:

`[[PromiseResult]]: 113`

Could anyone please help?

Comment: `r => r(value)` resolves on next tick, so your statement about creating already resolved promise is not correct. See `Promise.resolve`. note that expanding in devtools happens many ticks afterwards, so of course there is a result then.

Comment: @tehhowch - This feels new to me because informally what I know as soon as the first argument of our executor function is invoked, the promise is resolved. In our case that happens asynchronously so when we hit "return p;" in our last example, it should return a resolved promise, shouldnt it? 

we dont have any .then that we'll put its callback function into microtask queue for later execution.

Comment: @tehhowch Only if `value` is thenable. With a primitive value, it should fulfill immediately.  What really is taking the extra tick is the `resolve(p)` of the promise that the `async function` returns.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description): *'Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.'*

Comment: I still dont understand why "r => r(value)" will be called on the next tick? isnt the executor function supposed to run synchornously?

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because the JavaScript engine needs to "flatten" the returned promise.

```js
console.log(Promise.resolve(113)); //=> fulfilled
```

```js
const a = async () => 113;
console.log(a()); //=> fulfilled
```

```js
const b = async () => Promise.resolve(113);
console.log(b()); //=> pending
```

The last scenario logs a pending promise. This is probably because the JavaScript engine sees that you return a promise from an async function. In this scenario, when you `await b()`, you expect `113` as a result. An async function always returns a promise. If the resolved value (return value of an async function) of this promise is another promise then the promise is "flattened".

To better demonstrate the point, imagine the return value of `b` as (Firefox console notation):

```
Promise { <state>: "pending", <value>: Promse { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: 123 } }
```

Whereas the return value of both the first code block and `a` is:

```
Promse { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: 123 }
```

The flattening of nested promises is done by the engine and probably added to end of the event loop and thus ran after the current running context. Which means that the outer promise is *pending* until that happens.

This behaviour might be engine dependant, so I would not rely on this behaviour. A `Promise` instance is a promise of an eventual value and should be treated as such. Never expect a promise to resolve immediately. If you expect a fulfilled promise you are better of using a normal synchronous function, which avoids the use of promises.

Comment: This makes a bit more sense, im curios what function will be put onto the microtask queue for execution after all the sync code has done.

Comment: `b()` is equivalent to `new Promise(resolve => { const ret = Promise.resolve(123); resolve(ret); })`. @imheretolearn1 The microtask is the `ret.then(…)` invocation inside the `resolve(ret)` call (that accesses the inner promise's result to resolve the outer promise with it). It is not necessary in theory, but the ECMAScript spec mandates it.