# LONG: Why if we return a promise from our async function, its not immediately resolved?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

**Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question, I've been trying to find the answer to my question for a good while now but still no luck and that's causing me not to progress further in my JS learning!**

**Q:** Why even if we return a resolved promise from our async function, it's not immediately resolved?

Now MDN is teaching me this:

> Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an
> async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly
> wrapped in a promise.

This means, both the functions below f1 and f2, are equivalent!

```
async function f1(){
    
    return 100;
}
 
    async function f2(){
    
    return Promise.resolve(100);
}
    
    console.log(f1());
    console.log(f2());
```

However, we get different logs:

One logs: Promise {: 100}

Second logs: Promise pending

What's even more confusing is, when I expand the second promise's, even tho it says its pending, i see [[PromiseResult]]: 100.

Now my naive programming experience suggests, only if a value (string, num, arr, obj etc) is returned from the async function, the promise our async function returns by default will be resolved to that value!

But if our async function returns a promise that we ourself made inside our async function, then the default promise that async function  returns wont be returned, instead the promise we made inside our async function will be returned.

But that raises another question, what if we have await in our function? Await immediately returns a pending promise and whatever value we return from our async function is resolved with the promise our async function returns but again, what if we're returning a function?

A friend of mine told me if we are returning a resolved promise from our async function, some anonymous task is registered into the microtask queue which when run (after all the sync code,) unpacks the value from our the secondary promise and finally resolves our default promise returned by async function with that value and that seems to be working!

To test this assumption, I wrote this code:

```
   let o = new Promise(function (r){
    r(100)
});

o.then(function first(){console.log(p)})
.then(function second(){console.log(p)})

async function f(){

return new Promise(function (r){
    r(100)
})
}

let p = f();
```

Our o promise is gonna be resolved immediately so our first .then cb will be pushed to the microtask queue, like this maybe!

MICROTASK_QUEUE = [function first(){console.log(p)}]

On the next line we run f(), it goes inside f and sees we're returning a resolved promise so it returns a pending promise into p!

Now our microtask is like this:

MICROTASK_QUEUE = [function first(){console.log(p)}, someTaskThatWillUnpackOurPromiseAndResolveOurPromiseReturnedByTheAsyncFunctionByThatValue]

Our sync code is done, so we run our first task from microtask queue which happens to be our first .then, this one: function first(){console.log(p)}

This one is run and as expected, prints pending! Since this returns nothing, it returns undefined but since the promise's root .then is resolved, now our microtask queue looks like this after registering another .then.

MICROTASK_QUEUE = [someTaskThatWillUnpackOurPromiseAndResolveOurPromiseReturnedByTheAsyncFunctionByThatValue, function second(){console.log(p)}]

Now, this function is run someTaskThatWillUnpackOurPromiseAndResolveOurPromiseReturnedByTheAsyncFunctionByThatValue() (maybe internally unlike our .then functions)

now at this point promise that was earlier returned by our async function should be resolved with the value we resolved in our custom-made function, correct?

Now finally event loop checks the microtask queue and finds the final function to run, this one:

function second(){console.log(p)}

now why does this still return a pending promise?

I think there's still one more step I'm missing in this whole equation because if I put the 3rd .then, it finally logs this "Promise {: 100}" which is what I'm after!

```
let o = new Promise(function (r){
    r(100)
});

o.then(x => console.log(p))
.then(x => console.log(p))
.then(x => console.log(p))
async function f(){

return new Promise(function (r){
    r(100)
})
}

let p = f();
```

**I'm thankful to you if you read this far and it'd be greatly appreciated if someone could answe this**

Comment: You're calling async but you're not awaiting the calls to your promises, one will pass the other one won't would be my guess. f1 looks like it's being treated default.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` is always guaranteed to complete only after the next frame ends

Comment: p is the return of f() which returns  promise. Not sure why you are logging it in each `then()` of last code block. or why you have 3 duplicate then chained together. In last two then `x` is undefined due to no return from previous then. Very confusing

Comment: I don't see exactly how this is different from yesterday's question which was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67839588/1048572)?

Comment: "*But if our async function returns a promise that we ourself made inside our async function, then the default promise that async function returns wont be returned, instead the promise we made inside our async function will be returned.*" - no, that's not what happens. Your doubt about `await` followed by a returned promise brought you back on track - it *always* resolves the default promise with the `return` value, whatever that value is and whenever the `return` evaluates (immdiately vs. asynchronously). Your friend is right.

Comment: @Bergi - Hey, thanks for the response! So if an anonymous task is registered into the microtask queue which unpacks the value from our promise thats ultimately returned in our default promise returned by the async function, why didnt we get our p resolved logged in the 2nd .then? Instead we got into the 3rd .then. As I said, I think there's still one key step im missing in this whole equation bcs if our first task of unpacking the value is run first, we should see the p resolved in the second .then but we see in the third

Answer (score 3):

You should ignore the exact timing and ordering of the microtask jobs, it is not relevant for writing code - if you have dependencies between sections of asynchronous code, make them explicit, do not rely on queuing.

But it's fun to look at the internals of the JS engine anyway, so…

> But if our async function returns a promise that we ourself made inside our async function, then the default promise that async function returns wont be returned, instead the promise we made inside our async function will be returned.

No, that's not what happens. Your doubt about `await` followed by a returned promise brought you back on track - it *always* resolves the default promise with the `return` value, whatever that value is and whenever the `return` evaluates (immediately vs. asynchronously). Your friend is right.

> Now, this function is run: someTaskThatWillUnpackOurPromiseAndResolveOurPromiseReturnedByTheAsyncFunctionByThatValue() (maybe internally unlike our .then functions)
>
> now at this point promise that was earlier returned by our async function should be resolved with the value we resolved in our custom-made function, correct?

Not quite. You assumed that this unpacking happens unlike our `.then()` functions. But this is a potential optimisation that ES6 did fail to specify. Instead, it happens exactly like calling the `.then()` method - and not just "like": it indeed just *does* call the `.then()` method, which is necessary to resolve ordinary thenables, without taking a look whether the target is a native promise or a thenable.

And what the invoked `.then(resolve, reject)` method does is to schedule yet another job with the callback, which causes the outer promise to be resolved only after one additional tick.

You can compare the timings between the following functions:

```
const fulfilled = Promise.resolve('a');
async function a() {
  return {
    then(onFulfillment, onRejection) {
      console.log('promise then');
      fulfilled.then(onFulfillment, onRejection);
    }
  };
}
async function b() {
  return {
    then(onFulfillment, onRejection) {
      console.log('immediate then');
      onFulfillment('b');
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Referring to the code in OP's question, i have a small confusion. I have created a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wbS0h0QK) where i have added my understanding of how OP's code executes but there's a point in my explanation where i explain my confusion. I would really appreciate if you can clarify it for me. Also feel free to point out any other gaps in my understanding of OP's code.

Comment: @Yousaf "*As the promise is resolved, a micro-task is queued in the micro-task queue.*" - no. Microtasks are queued only if there is something to do - i.e. if a thenable is to be awaited, or a handler is to be executed. The first one is queued when the `o.then()` call registers a fulfillment handler on an already fulfilled promise.

Comment: @Yousaf "*your answer suggests that the "innerPromise" will be unwrapped by calling "then" method on it. What exactly happens here? What is `innerPromise.then` method called with as arguments for fulfilment handler and rejection handler?*" - with the `resolve` and `reject` functions of the outer promise. See the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-53), which predates ES6 but was followed quite closely. You can also check the example in my answer and log the `then` arguments there, they should be native (but named) functions.

Comment: thank you for your response. I think i understand this now. Is [this](https://pastebin.com/0mf9qENt) how "outerPromise" wraps and is _resolved_ to the "innerPromise"?

Comment: @Yousaf Yes, precisely.

Comment: This confusion was bugging me since i saw this question but couldn't really find an explanation. Although i feel comfortable using promises in my code, but still i feel like there are some minor gaps in my understanding of promises and micro-tasks. You just helped fill couple of those gaps for me today. THANK YOU! (not sure what's happening but somehow i am unable to tag you in my comments)

Comment: @Yousaf One really shouldn't need to understand microtasks to use promises. [Code never should rely on queuing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761869/1048572) (an engine implementation detail) but [only on promise chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400182/1048572). I also maintain the opinion that the scheduling as specified in ES6 is inefficient and should change, similar to how the scheduling of `await` in fact *did* change after ES8.

Comment: @Yousaf I think you can't tag me since there are only two participants in the comment thread, and I get notifications anyway given I'm the answer author.

Comment: _"One really shouldn't need to understand microtasks to use promises. Code never should rely on queuing (an engine implementation detail) but only on promise chaining"_ - correct but still its nice to know the inner workings. I always believed that a micro-task is queued whenever a promise is resolved and i was wrong but it didn't matter when using promises in my code. Similarly, i knew that one promise can _resolve_ to another promise but never really knew exactly HOW that happens. I am glad to have those things clarified.

Comment: @Yousaf - Just to give my 1 cent, just know as soon as we have .then, the cb function we pass into that .then is pushed into the hidden internal array called onFulfillment and once our promise is resolved, all the functions from that array are put into the microtask queue for later execution! 

(I'm noob at async so obviously i donna wanna be giving complex advices but for this one, I hope if someone is reading this find this helpful. :D It certainly helped me learn Promise on at the surface level. Also sorry my bad English)

Comment: @imheretolearn1, I think that's [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76936887/does-the-js-engine-create-a-new-microtask-that-will-execute-every-handler-chaine).